# How is a signal multiplied with the window functions?

Tags: fft, window-functions, window

How the input signal get multiplied with the window functions like Hamming, Hanning, Blackman, etc?

I have tried to multiply the input signal of $10\textrm{ MHz}$ sampled at $100\textrm{ MHz}$ using the Blackmann window function. The output graph is 
[image]

- How is the multiplication perfomed ?

The input signal is $1\times 64$ row matrix, the Blackman window generates its samples in $64\times 1$ column matrix. The multiplication generates a $64\times 64$ matrix i.e one sample of input signal is multiplied to 64 samples of the window function. For a particular point sample there are 64 sample value. I intend to calculate 128-point FFT with padding zeros.

- So for a particular sample point which value should be considered to calculate FFT?

Here is my code :

```
N = 64; % signal length (power of 2)
T = 10*(10^-9) ; % sampling period (and rate) is set to 1
A = 1; % sinusoid amplitude
phi = 0; % phase of zero
f = 10*(10^6); % frequency (under Nyquist limit)
nT = [0:N-1]*T; % discrete time axis
w = blackman(N,'periodic');
x1 = A*cos(2*pi*f*nT);
x = w*x1  ; % windowed signal
subplot (311);
stem (x1);
wp = [w;zeros((zpf-1)*N,1)];
subplot (313);
stem (x);
subplot (312);
stem (w);
disp (x1);
disp (w);
disp (x);
```

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP!  You appear to have done the right thing. What do you think is wrong? Please edit your question with the extra information.

Comment: I would say his problem is that he wanted to obtain his original signal weighted by the window, but instead he is obtaining a set of signals corresponding to his window function weighted by each sample of his signal. In my opinion it's just a problem of Matlab code, he did a matrix product instead of a dotted product.

Comment: Husain Asif : you should post your code, I'm pretty sure it's just a simple syntax issue

Comment: @FlorentEcochard can you explain how to perform the dotted product

Comment: @HusainAsif with a dot... `A .* B`. As said earlier, post your code if you want more than guesses. [source](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html)

Comment: @FlorentEcochard                                                                                    
N = 64; % signal length (power of 2)
T = 10*(10^-9) ; % sampling period (and rate) is set to 1
A = 1; % sinusoid amplitude
phi = 0; % phase of zero
f = 10*(10^6); % frequency (under Nyquist limit)
nT = [0:N-1]*T; % discrete time axis
w = blackman(N,'periodic');
x1 = A*cos(2*pi*f*nT);
x = w*x1  ; % windowed signal
subplot (311);
stem (x1);
wp = [w;zeros((zpf-1)*N,1)];
subplot (313);
stem (x);
subplot (312);
stem (w);
disp (x1);
disp (w);
disp (x);

Comment: not here, in your question, with proper formatting please.

Comment: ~~Also as @PeterK. asked you, please clarify your actual problem~~ EDIT I haden't seen your edit, sorry. The solution though, if I understood correctly, is to replace the line : `x = w*x1` by `x = w'.*x1`

Comment: @FlorentEcochard yes you have understood clearly. By performing dot product I got the result I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: So the apostrophy transposes your vector w to make it same dimension as x1, and then the `.*` performs an element-wise product between the two, effectively weighting your signal by the window

Comment: It seems like I confused the vocabulary : ***dot product*** is actually not the right word for `.*`. I should have said ***element-wise*** product. It is explained in @Fat32's answer below. Sorry about that, English isn't my first language

Comment: @FlorentEcochard strictly speaking a **dot product** is defined not between signals but **vectors** as $\bar{a} \cdot \bar{b} = |a||b|cos(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{3} a_i b_i$ . Inside MATLAB a vector is represented as a 1D **matrix** and all vector operations should be converted to equivalent matrix operations. Between two matrices we have the **matrix product**; $C(i,j) = (A \star B)(i,j) = \sum_{k=1}^{M} A_{ik} B_{kj}$. Now for 1D matrices of proper size the matrix product expression becomes identical to dot product expression hence you can get the same numerical result by performing either.

Comment: @Fat32 interesting! Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @FlorentEcochard in signal processing we define the signal product such as $v[n]=w[n]x[n]$ which is neither a dot product nor a matrix product. In matlab discrete-time sequences are also represented as matrices of proper size. Therefore in order to implement a signal product we need **element by element** product between two matrcies which computes the sample by sample product between two signals indeed. The symbol $.*$ is used to realize that kind of a product. It can also be used to alternatively realize a dot product between two vectors as long as the matrices have proper dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab window functions such as *hamming(N)* returns the $N$ point Hamming window sequence $w[n]$ in a $N \times 1$ matrix (a column vector).

Therefore if your sequence $x[n]$ is represented in a **row vector** of size $1 \times N$ then for obtaining the sample-by-sample product $x[n]w[n]$, you should either transpose $w[n]$ or the other $x[n]$, so that their dimensions permit the correct sample-by-sample multiplication in between and produce the output sequence $v[n]=w[n]x[n]$ represented in a matrix of the size $N \times 1$ or $1 \times N$ depending on which one you have transposed.

```
v0 = x.*w      % x: Nx1, w: Nx1, v0: Nx1
v1 = x .* w'   % x: 1xN, w: Nx1, transpose w => v1: 1xN
v3 = x' .* w   % x: 1xN, w: Nx1, transpose x => v3: Nx1
```

Note that if the transposed signal is **complex** valued, then you should use the **conjugate transpose** instead :

```
v1 = conj(x').* w  % x[n] was complex valued...
```

Note also that the sample by sample product is perfomed by the [$.*$](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) operation under Matlab;

```
  v = x .* w    % is a sample by sample product implementing v[n] = x[n]w[n]
```

If you omit the period and use the $*$ alone, you get **matrix product** or the **dot product** in case of vectors involved.

For this case when you have two vectors, $x$ of size $N \times 1$ and $w$ of size $1 \times N$, then their matrix product would produce a matrix of size $N \times N$

```
v = x * w    % x: N x 1, w: 1 x N => v: N x N
```